# row wise comparison and update in new column

Tags: r

I would like to add a third column to the dataframe(df) depending on col.b
and a row wise comparison. I want col.c to increase by one each row except if the element in col.b is below 0.1. If this is the case the value in col.c should be the same as the previous in col.c.

```
df    <-structure(list(col.a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
        9, 10), col.b = c(0.176776695296637, 0.166666666666667, 
         0.171692917879238, 0.247435829652697, 0.0909090909090909, 
         0.244948974278318, 0.142857142857143, 0.072005229038445, 
         0.202030508910442, 0.248451997499977)), .Names = c("col.a", 
        "col.b"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

> df
  col.a           col.b   
      1  0.176776695296637
      2  0.166666666666667
      3  0.171692917879238
      4  0.247435829652697
      5 0.0909090909090909
      6  0.244948974278318
      7  0.142857142857143
      8  0.072005229038445
      9  0.202030508910442
     10  0.248451997499977`
```

Desired output

```
> df
  col.a           col.b       col.c
      1  0.176776695296637    1
      2  0.166666666666667    2
      3  0.171692917879238    3
      4  0.247435829652697    4
      5 0.0909090909090909    4
      6  0.244948974278318    5
      7  0.142857142857143    6 
      8  0.072005229038445    6
      9  0.202030508910442    7
     10  0.248451997499977    8
```

So far I came up with a loop which kind of works but the counting is off and it becomes awfully slow when used for my large dataframe

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
   ifelse(df$col.b[i] >0.1 ,m <- df$col.a[i], m <-df$col.a[i-1])          
   df$col.c[i] <- m   }
```

I look for a faster way to realize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to just do a `cumsum` on the logical `vector`

```
with(df, cumsum(col.b > 0.1))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 4 5 6 6 7 8
```